# Easy way to comparing dates between ranges in C#

Tags: c#

Im making reservation system.

For example, i have available offer to reserve from time to time:

```
Offer: 8AM - 8PM (in one day, for example in 1/12/2018)
OR
Offer: 7/12/2019 8AM - 10/12-2019 8PM
```

Someone reserve part of this time, for example:

```
First reservation: 12AM - 2PM (same day as offer)
OR
First reservation: 7/12/2019 8AM - 8/12/2019 8AM
```

As you can see, we still have available time: `8AM - 12 AM` and `2PM - 8PM`.

Now, someone want to reserve time:

```
Second reservation: 8AM - 10AM (same day as offer)
OR 
Second reservation: 10/12/2019 0AM - 10/12/2019 8PM
```

Then, someone want to make another reservation:

```
Third reservation: 2PM - 8PM (same day as offer)
OR
Third reservation: 8/12/2019 0AM - 9/12/2019 8AM
```

From scenerio above, time available in offer:

```
Available time in offer (after 3 reservations): 10AM - 12AM (same day as offer)

//i didnt write example with couple of days because it is too hard to calculate it in mind
```

Now, my question. Im looking for solution to validate request with `DateTimes` that is between some period of time.

I started to code something:

```
        //there is no Offer offer in this method, because i check request times
        //with offer step before
        private bool TimeOfReservationIsValid(Command request)
        {
            bool result = true;

            var reservations = _context.Reservations.Where(r => r.OfferId == request.OfferId);

            if (reservations.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var reservation in reservations)
                {
                    if (request.StartOfRent <= reservation.StartOfRent
                        && request.StartOfRent < reservation.EndOfRent
                        && request.EndOfRent <= reservation.EndOfRent
                        && request.EndOfRent > reservation.StartOfRent)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (request.StartOfRent >= reservation.StartOfRent
                        && request.StartOfRent < reservation.EndOfRent
                        && request....)
                    {
                        //i think in this code it can be too much if statemantes?
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

But there is too much cases. In code above, im checking if `request` collides with any of `reservation`. If it collide with one of them, `result = false` and i delete `request`.

I know i could do validation in `ClientSide` (for example in frontend, sending only good requests) but i want to make logic to validate this `request times` in backend.

Is there any library or solution for my problem?

As you can see, when we have reservation on the middle of offer rent time, first i need to check if request match with first free offer time, then i need to check second free time (if `request` match with free `offer` time). Maybe you struggle with similiar problem to mine?

**EDIT:**

I added full date to my offers examples. My `Reservations` system works on full `DateTime` with year, month, days etc

Comment: there is [DateTime.Subtract(..)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.subtract?view=netframework-4.8) and [DateTime.Add(..)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.add?view=netframework-4.8) methods that may help you.

Comment: @mjwills  its time with `Date` (year, month, day etc, i need it because my system offers times on days too). In code, its simple `public DateTime StartOfRent { get; set }`, i do nothing with this.

Comment: @mjwills so yes, you can reserve day or two if it is available in `Offer`

Comment: So you want to check if the period in request intersects with any period in the reservations collection?

Comment: Yes, i starting to understand what is wrong with my logic with code above. I need to compare `periods` of time, not `single` dates. Do you think `TimeSpan` will be good solution to comparing periods of time in middle of `Start` and `End` times?

Comment: I would use [Flower's range](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Range.html). So I can simplify the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if any range overlap.

```
   var overlaps =
       _context.Reservations
          .Where(r => r.OfferId == request.OfferId)
          .Any(r => request.EndOfRent >= reservation.StartOfRent && 
                    reservation.EndOfRent >= request.StartOfRent)
```